# Fourier representation of a function with changing period

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

I learned that the Fourier representation of a periodic function $f(t)$ with period $T$ is $\sum \limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} C_k e^{i2\pi k t/T}$ with appropriate constants $\{C_k\}$.

My question: Is it possible to have a similar representation if the period is also a function of $t$, $T_t$?

(I am not a mathematician. So, kindly explain your answer in details, and also cite appropriate books and papers, if possible. Thanks!)

Comment: If the "period depends on t" it is not a period. The fourier series essentially describes a function defined on a finite interval of width T. This becomes the period of the Fourier series.

Comment: I'd say what you are asking for is possible, but involves a good bit of heavy machinery. There is a concept of variable bandwidth, explained for example here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06663. Theorem 1.2 is essentially the generalisation of the discrete Fourier representation to the case of variable bandwidth functions. Now I realise you said I should explain in detail and I really haven't done that. Hopefully, the paper is sufficiently detailled, though.